# Problems with DateTime, it appears with 00:00:00

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, c#-4.0, razor

I have my database which has a DateTime type for Birthdate value when I register the user.

When I receive my data back, to edit the register form, I have my Razor like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Birthdate)
```

The date shows like this: 28/05/1983 00:00:00

I want only the birthdate, obviously. In my Controller, I have this:

```
User userset = db.User.Find(id);
return View(userset);
```

Very simple... Could anyone help me to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using `Html.TextBox` instead of using `Html.TextBoxFor`.

```
@Html.TextBox("Birth date", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.Birthdate))
```

Comment: Your approach seems to be very simple to do, but in this case my TextBoxFor content would mix with this one. How would I get this data in my Controller?

Answer (score 3):

Set the DisplayFormat data annotation above the property in your model.

```
public class User
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then instead of using `@Html.TextBoxFor(..)` use `@Html.EditorFor(...)`.

See the [DisplayFormatAttribute MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) for more details.

If you have generated your data model using EF you can simply create a meta class for your class to apply data annotations.  For example, if my db file is called `MyDB.edmx`, create a buddy class file called `MyDB.cs`.  Then inside there, I would extend the `User` class by attaching a metadata class to it and specifying the data annotation in the metaclass:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public partial class User{ }

public class UserMetaData
{
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

See [Scott Gu's post on validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx), mainly the section *'But what if we are using a graphical tool for our ORM mappings?'*.

Comment: Thank you @link664, but I cannot do that, I have my generated code for my database context classes, it doesnt accept to place this line you showed inside it... theres any other way to do that?

Comment: How have you generated your database context classes, using the Entity Framework?

Comment: I imported System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; to use in my generated Model class, yes I generated using EF, I posted [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] as you suggested over Birthdate line, but it keeps not working...

Comment: Did you create a buddy class like I mentioned above or did you just directly edit the generated entity framework file?

Comment: Hi @link664, I tried to post all this code in my App.cs, de main file as you told, and it didnt work. I tried to move the first line for User.cs and keep the rest in App.cs class but it also didnt work, as I`m newbie in MVC3 and Entity Framework, I dont know where I`m doing my mistakes...

Comment: @RubiaGardini - just realized you were using TextBoxFor and not EditorFor, which will explain why it's not working.  Have updated my answer with this addition.

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker from jQuery is a better approach to receive date input from user. It is particularly helpful to avoid various date format confusion.

More details on: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx